# Extract text from email then send text

Tags: email, awk, sed, grep, sms

I have alerts setup with my bank for whenever a transaction occurs. I have been trying to extract only the Date and the amount and forward that as a text message to myself.

Here is what the alert email looks like:

```
FIRSTNAME LAST NAME

A transaction has been posted to your BANKNAME ACCOUNTNAME, and is within the parameters you set for triggering this alert.  

The transaction was on 06/20/2014 in the amount of ($40.00).  For recent account history, including transaction descriptions and running balances, sign on to BANKNAME Account Manager (online banking) and click on the account name.


BANKNAME Disclaimer: This transmittal is intended only for the use of the individual or entity to which it is addressed and may contain information that is privileged, confidential and exempt from disclosure under applicable law. If the reader of this transmittal is not the intended recipient, or the employee or agent responsible for delivering the transmittal to the intended recipient, you are notified that any dissemination, distribution or copying of this communication is strictly prohibited. If you have received this e-mail in error, please immediately notify the sender by e-mail and delete this message from your computer.
```

I have been able to grep, awk, and sed but only can get the entire line to display.

```
:~# nawk '/The transaction was on/,/For recent account history/' alert.txt
The transaction was on 06/20/2014 in the amount of ($40.00).  For recent account history, including transaction descriptions and running balances, sign on to BANKNAME Account Manager (online banking) and click on the account name.
```

What can I do to change the command to extract only the date and the amount so that the result would look something like this:

```
06/20/2014 $40.00
```

The plan is to take that output and send it to my self as a text message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below `grep` command to get the date and the amount,

```
$ grep -oP '\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|\$[^\)]*' file | paste -d' ' - -
06/20/2014 $40.00
```

You could do it also in GNU `sed`,

```
$ sed -nr 's~^.*([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}).*\((\$[^)]*)\).*$~\1 \2~p' file
06/20/2014 $40.00
```

Comment: I like this (especially the grep one) better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk -vRS=\  '/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/ {d=$0} /\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ {print d, substr($0, 2, length - 3); exit}'
```

Explanation:

```
/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/

Matches 1 or more digits, a slash, 1 or more digits, a slash, and 1 or more digits.

[0-9] matches a single digit character in 0, 1, 2, ..., 9
+     causes the previous entity to be matched 1 or more times
\/    is a literal slash (the backslash "escapes" it so it doesn't terminate
      the pattern)

/\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/

Matches a dollar sign, 1 or more digits, a period, and 1 or more digits.

\$ matches a literal dollar sign (a dollar sign is otherwise an anchor matching
   the end of the string)
\. matches a literal period (a period otherwise matches any character)
```

Comment: can you explain what this is doing?  Complex regular expressions are very difficult to understand, especially if you are not familiar with regex.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I added a bit of explanation. But Avinash's `grep` solution is probably better.